# Работа с input type="text"

Tags: javascript

Требуется из `input type="text"` взять введенное пользователем значение и, по клику на кнопку, добавить к элементу с помощью JavaScript. 
Пытался через `onClick="document.getElementById('seventhOne').innerHTML+=text;"` — не работало

Answer (score 2):

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('seventhOne').innerHTML+=document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value">Click</button> 
<input type="text" value="test "/>
<div id="seventhOne">start </div>
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить алгоритм работы querySelector в этом коде? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Dream1ngFly `querySelector` возвращает первый элемент, удовлетворяющий селектору в параметре. В данном случае - это элемент `input` с атрибутом `type="text"`. Прошу учесть, что это только пример. В Вашей разметке этот инпут может иметь атрибуты `id` или `class`, позволяющие сделать селектор более конкретным.

Comment: @Igor я бы сказал это работает частично, потому что если нажать больше одного раза, ну сами понимаете)